# Fermenting Peppers in brine with 1 table spoon salt to 0.9 L Jar, too low salt? Botulism risk?

Tags: fermentation, brining, botulism

I have fermented some peppers, but after doing so, I started to doubt the ratio of salt might be too low;
I used 1 table spoon of salt, for a jar of 0.9 L; does this create a safe environment against botulism?

It has been about a week, and there some big bubbles floating to the top

Comment: The amount of salt in a tablespoon will vary quite a bit depending on the type and coarseness of the salt. Are you able to weigh a tablespoon of the salt you used?

Comment: @Sneftel not really unfortunately

Comment: @Sneftel I think the amount of salt would correspond between 1.5% to 2%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A brine like that will not by itself prevent bacteria such as clostridium botulinum from growing. But that’s not a problem. For lacto-fermented vegetables, it is rather the acidity which makes a hostile environment. Lactic fermentation is quite dependable and safe; if things go wrong, they will go *obviously* wrong (rotten smell, colorful mold everywhere), not silent-and-deadly wrong.

Comment: ok, so I can tell you results after a week: I can see bubbles, and the smell of the pepper is like enhanced, like there were more peppers in the jar, it is stronger than normal smell of pepper, and actually I tasted it (one hour ago), and was quite salty taste... what would you say?

Comment: I would say, lactic fermentation is quite dependable and safe.

Answer (score -1):

The standard is 6 - 10 percent salt to water. As a general rule of thumb 8 percent for veggies is my goto ratio. This means 80 grams of salt per liter of water. You can add 50 ml of vinegar if you desire but it is optional. A very important point to note is that different brands of salt vary greatly in volume, so you must weigh the salt. Also do use fine salt, it is just more suitable for brines.

Comment: wow, but this percent will be too salty, how do you manage to balance the salty taste afterwards?